# How can I setup a proxy in a Selenium Chrome container?

Tags: selenium, docker, proxy, automated-tests, selenium-chromedriver

I have a docker-compose.yml file with well-known environment variables to reach our corporate proxy:

```
---
version: '2.2'
# adapted from:
# https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/docker-selenium/wiki/Getting-Started-with-Docker-Compose
# docker-compose --force-recreate

services:
  chrome:
    privileged: True
    image: "selenium/standalone-chrome:3.11.0"
    ports:
      - "4444:4444"
    volumes:
      - /dev/shm:/dev/shm
    environment:
      - TZ="UT"
      - http_proxy=http://proxy.lan:8080
      - https_proxy=http://proxy.lan:8080
      - no_proxy=
      #- SE_OPTS=-Dhttp.proxyHost=proxy.lan -Dhttp.proxyPort=8080
    network_mode: host
```

When I run wget in the container, then the proxy is used as expected.

```
    --2018-05-02 12:30:45--  http://google.com/
Resolving proxy.lan (proxy.lan)... 192.168.33.141
Connecting to proxy.lan (proxy.lan)|192.168.33.141|:8080... connected.
Proxy request sent, awaiting response... 301 Moved Permanently
Location: http://www.google.com/ [following]
--2018-05-02 12:30:45--  http://www.google.com/
Reusing existing connection to proxy.lan:8080.
Proxy request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: unspecified [text/html]
Saving to: ‘/dev/null’

/dev/null                                              [ <=>                                                                                                          ]  10.81K  --.-KB/s    in 0s

2018-05-02 12:30:46 (310 MB/s) - ‘/dev/null’ saved [11073]
```

However, when I try to run the container with `SE_OPTS="-Dhttp.proxyHost=proxy.lan -Dhttp.proxyPort=8080"`, then I see a stacktrace:

```
Exception in thread "main" com.beust.jcommander.ParameterException: Was passed main parameter '"-Dhttp.proxyHost=proxy.lan' but no main parameter was defined in your arg class.
```

There is an [unmerged PR](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/docker-selenium/pull/699), but I fear the urgency to use a proxy in testing in corporate environment might not be felt by the Se dev. Maybe there is an alternative solution.

Comment: You could fork that project and merge in the PR yourself?